# Ocaml - Print length of branches in bush (like tree) on the principle of the left-to-depth

Tags: tree, ocaml

I have one Ocaml example, with which I'm dealing. I need to display length of all branches in some kind of tree on the principle of left-to-depth. So if we have this tree:

```
     4

  2     6

1  3  5  7
```

I would like to display length of all branches in tree. Do you have some idea?

We have type of bush, which is defined as follows:

```
# type 'a bush = 
   Null
   | One of 'a * 'a bush
   | Two of 'a bush * 'a * 'a bush;;
```

Write a function "brancheslength" 'a bush -> unit, which displays the length of the branches of a bush on the principle of left-to-depth!

Comment: What is the definition of the length of a branch? Do you mean the total number of branches in a bush? or some distance between individual nodes? (for example, between nodes 1 and 2). We also usually like to see an attempt to better explain any misunderstood concepts that this problem developed from.

Comment: I think (because I don't have detailed instructions), that we are looking for all branches. So in our case, we have 4 branches, and they are all length of 3. Then we can put this in list, like this: [3;3;3;3]. So this is what we need.

Answer (score 2):

According to your definition of the length of a branch, you can go through your tree recursively this way :

```
let rec branches_length bush depth = match bush with
| Null -> [depth]
| One (a, b) -> (branches_length b (depth + 1))
| Two (a, b, c) -> (branches_length a (depth + 1))@(branches_length c (depth + 1))
```